# Removing duplicates but only the one with an older date remains in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `dbo.Inbox` which has 4 columns: `[Id]`, `[UserId]`, `[Email]`, `[CreationDate]`.

I am using the following SQL Query to remove the rows where `[UserId]` and `[Email]` are the same. However, it deletes the row with an older `[CreationDate]`.

```
WITH cte AS (
            SELECT
                Id,
                UserId,
                Email,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY
                        UserId,
                        Email
                    ORDER BY
                        UserId,
                        Email
                ) row_num
             FROM
                Inbox
        )
        DELETE FROM cte
        WHERE row_num > 1;
```

How should I change the above query so when I delete the duplicated rows, only the ones having the older `[CreationDate]` remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order the rows by descending CreationDate:

```
WITH cte AS (
            SELECT
                Id,
                UserId,
                Email,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY
                        UserId,
                        Email
                    ORDER BY
                        CreationDate DESC
                ) row_num
             FROM
                Inbox
        )
        DELETE FROM cte
        WHERE row_num > 1;
```